# PowerShell releasing the file lock created by the last criteria test

Tags: powershell

I need to select images based on size, width, and datemodified, and move them, as well as rename them. Here is my script so far:

```
Add-Type -Assembly System.Drawing
Get-ChildItem -path C:\temp\images |
  Where-Object { $_.Length -ge 250Kb -and $_.lastwritetime -gt (get-date).addDays(-5) -and [Drawing.Image]::FromFile($_.FullName).Width -eq 1920 } | 
  move-item –PassThru | Rename-Item -NewName {-join @($_.Name,'.jpg')}
```

The problem is FromFile method is locking the file and preventing the move with this error message:

> move-item : The process cannot access the file because it is being
> used by another process.

Comment: [1] PLEASE change your title to reflect your actual Question. your problem is not multiple criteria ... it is releasing the file lock created by the last criteria test. ///// [2] backticks are NOT needed after a pipe. [*grin*]

Comment: Good suggestion Lee_Dailey -- done!

Comment: thank you! [*grin*]

Answer (score 2):

You need to find the other process using the file, with for instance:

```
$lockedFile = "path/to/locked/file"
$lockingProcessID = Get-Process | foreach {$processVar = $_;$_.Modules `
    | foreach {if($_.FileName -eq $lockedFile) {$processVar.id}}}
```

and then kill the process:

```
Stop-Process -ID $lockingProcessID -Force
```

then try again to move your file.

Comment: Thanks for the response - I tried your suggestion from piped results, but I'm getting this error: Stop-Process : Cannot evaluate parameter 'Id' because its argument is specified as a script block and there is no input. A script block cannot be evaluated without input